# If every bad event is because of karma, how can anyone ever murder an arhat or buddha?

Tags: karma, arhats, evil, hells

If every bad event is because of karma, how can anyone ever murder an arhat?

> Killing an Arhat (enlightened being)

is one of the [ānantarika-kamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anantarika-karma) actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Buddha once said that Devadatta's throwing a rock and hurting Buddha's foot was caused by Buddha's past bad karma from a previous life.

Even for Buddha's and non-returners/Arhats past karma keeps getting resolved until parinibbana.

Answer (score 2):

> If every bad event is because of karma, how can anyone ever murder an arhat or buddha?

Question premise might reveal an internal inconsistency - every bad event is not *only* caused by Kamma.

The Buddha taught that there are [*5 natural laws (Niyamas)*](http://www.purifymind.com/BuddhismKarma.htm), that causes physical and mental events to take place;

> *1.    The seasonal laws (Utu-Niyama) related to temperature, seasons and other physical events*
>
> *2. The biological laws (Bija-Niyama) related to seeds and physical organic order*
>
> *3. The physical law (Citta-Niyama) related to the processes of consciousness, or to the nature of consciousness which recognises objects etc.*
>
> *4. The Kammic law (Kamma-Niyama) related to the law of Kamma, (good deeds and bad deeds and their results)*
>
> *5. The Natural laws (Dhamma-Niyama) related to certain events: the general law of cause and effect, causality conditionally and unconditionally 
>   Trying to further interpretate it will just carry over into  imagination. Only a fully enlightened Buddha can know the intricate workings of kamma.*

Comment: might, but might not. thanks for the answer, but i won't accept it yet :)

Comment: My person wonders about the source and the context of this set of five. Is that known and provide able, Nyom Lanka? Weather,food, beings... is said to be a matter of given strong causes, e.g. kamma, when thinking on 1-3.